# Call WebAPI then parse part of json result

Tags: c#

this is a basic web api call using `HttpClient` and parse some part of the result, this was working as expected, but the part inside the `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` doesnt seems right. It feels like it can be simplified, but I don't know how.

```
static async Task<List<Hero>> GetHero(string url, string urlParameters)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    using (var response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var heroes = new List<Hero>();
            var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var deserializedjsonResult = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
            var resultHeroes = deserializedjsonResult["result"]["heroes"].ToList();

            resultHeroes.ForEach(x => heroes.Add(x.ToObject<Hero>()));

            return heroes;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

the api that I was calling will return something in this format

```
{
  "result": {
    "heroes": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    "villains": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    "extras": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
> ```

This needs to be disposed.

---

> ```
> using (var response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result)
> ```

Why don't you `await` this like you do with other awaitable APIs?

---

> ```
> static async Task<List<Hero>> GetHero(string url, string urlParameters)
> {
>     ..
>     return null;
> }
> ```

Methods returning collections should return an empty collection instead of `null` this means you should

```
return Task.FromResult(new List<Hero>());
```

---

As far as the `if` block is concerned you don't need the `heros` variable. With LINQ can create the list inplace:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var deserializedjsonResult = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
    var resultHeroes = deserializedjsonResult["result"]["heroes"];
    return resultHeroes.Select(x => x.ToObject<Hero>()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks, on the await on `client.GetAsync`, Im getting error, `'HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' `, any commennts on how I parse the result and put it to c# object?

Comment: @user140692 you should not `await` the `Result` but the `GetAsync`

Comment: thanks, im still getting used to the async/task. any idea about the part inside `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`?

Comment: WRT HttpClient needing to be disposed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708633/648075

Comment: @BCdotWEB same thing with Entity Framework, everyone claims it should be instantly disposed but by doing so you loose change tracking. or have to set some context properties over and over again. This is a really poor excuse for not disposing things. The necessity for setting the headers again for each request is such a bad excuse. You can always write an extension that does this for you. Besides in OP's example the HttpClient is not a field but a local variable so this does not apply here, this means --> dispose.

Comment: I would like to tack on that the return value (might) be better served as `IEnumerable<Hero>` rather than `List<Hero>`. And then the `return null;` can be replaced with `return Enumerable.Empty<Hero>();`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I find returning `IEnumerable<T>` from a method that actually produces a `List<T>` is a bad design because it means that the method might return a deferred collection so I automatically do `.ToList()` to actually  get the values but when I get a `List<T>` I know everything is there.

Comment: Then may I suggest `IList<T>` as an alternative to adhere to developing to interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few minor and some major suggestions.

```
static async Task<List<Hero>> GetHero(string url, string urlParameters)
```

Missing public/private. You are using a concrete type here, and you should be using an interface. The usual practice in .NET here is to take the "lowest common denominator", which in this case is `IEnumerable<Hero>` or slightly higher up is `ICollection<Hero>`. This way you can internally change the return type as long as it implements one of those interfaces. This does not prevent you using `.ToList()` because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio

Basically, use an interface. I would also strongly discourage `IList<T>` unless you really want to force the consumer to deal with lists. If you don't need the extra methods that `IList<T>`, then use the lower interface, and so on.

**ForEach**

The LINQ ForEach method is often regarded as a bad idea due to it causing multiple enumerations, and in fact one of the .NET developers themselves suggests not using it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

In your case, it can be rewritten to using `Select()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the last point. The article is about a LINQ `ForEach` extension but OP is using the `List<>.ForEach` API. It is also not suggesting to not use it but explains why there is no such extension. What do you mean by _causing multiple enumerations_?